# scroll_x works perfectly, but scroll_y will not follow the 'accelerations' of the player gravity

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I have a level class with the following code where the screen follows the player perfectly when the player meets a left and right threshold...

```py
    def scroll_x(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        player_x = player.rect.centerx
        direction_x = player.direction.x

        if player_x < screen_width/2 -8 and direction_x < 0:
            self.world_shift_x = 2
            player.speed = 0
        elif player_x > screen_width/2 +8 and direction_x > 0:
            self.world_shift_x = -2
            player.speed = 0
        else:
            self.world_shift_x = 0
            player.speed = 2

    def scroll_y(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        player_y = player.rect.centery
        direction_y = player.direction.y
        
        if player_y < screen_height/2 -8 and direction_y < 0:
            self.world_shift_y = 2
            
        elif player_y > screen_height/2 +8 and direction_y > 0:
            self.world_shift_y = -2
            
        else:
            self.world_shift_y = 0
          
    
    def run(self):
        #level tiles
        self.tiles.update(self.world_shift_x, self.world_shift_y)
        self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
        #player
        self.player.update()
        self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
        self.scroll_x()
        self.scroll_y()`
```

For reference, my player class is as follows...

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((tilesize,tilesize))
        self.image.fill((150,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.speed = 2
        self.grav = 0.2
        self.jump_speed = -2
        

    def get_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
        
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.jump()


    def apply_grav(self):
        self.direction.y += self.grav
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y
        if self.direction.y > 2:
            self.direction.y = 2

    def jump(self):
        self.direction.y = self.jump_speed

    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y 
        self.apply_grav()`
```

And tile class to update the shifting tiles:

```py
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,size):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
        self.image.fill((0,100,50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

    def update(self,x_shift,y_shift):
        self.rect.x += x_shift
        self.rect.y += y_shift`
```

Even after doing these, I cannot set the `self_world_y` to move with the accelerations of the player in the `scroll_y` function. As seen here, I have set it to 2 like the x axis, but this allows the player to jump and fall off the top and bottom of screen over time. How do I lock this value to the player's current speed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll with the speed of the player:

```py
def scroll_y(self):
    player = self.player.sprite
    player_y = player.rect.centery
    direction_y = player.direction.y
    
    if player_y < screen_height/2 -8 and direction_y < 0:
        self.world_shift_y = -direction_y
        
    elif player_y > screen_height/2 +8 and direction_y > 0:
        self.world_shift_y = -direction_y
        
    else:
        self.world_shift_y = 0
```

If the player falls, the movement is (`direction_y`) is added twice to the players position. Change the position only in `update`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def apply_grav(self):
        self.direction.y += self.grav
    
        # self.rect.y += self.direction.y    <--- DELETE
    
        if self.direction.y > 2:
            self.direction.y = 2
```